# Collision detection between 2 fill.Rect function

Tags: javascript, html, css, game-development

I have a game where one player is controlled by the arrow keys, and the other player is controlled by the WSAD keys. I have the map set up in a 600, 600 canvas and I want to add collision between the 2 fill.Rect players that I have in the game, to when the 2 players, are withing a certain radius of each other, it either ends the program, or displays text such as "game over"

Here is my code for js, and Html, and Css (TO VIEW CODE SNIPPET, YOU HAVE TO GO TO "FULL PAGE":

```js
//Canvas
mycan.style.display = "block";
mycan.height = 600;
mycan.width = 600;
//make players
let player = {x:511, y: 541, w:29, h:29};
let player2 = {x:60, y:31, w:30, h:29};


//Context
const ctx = mycan.getContext("2d");


//Start-position
ctx.fillRect(player.x, player.y, player.w, player.h);
ctx.fillRect(player2.x, player2.y, player2.w, player2.h);
//No-smooth-movement
window.onkeydown = move = (e) => {
    let key = e.keyCode;
  //player1(red)
    if     (key === 68 && player2.x <= mycan.width-30) {player2.x += 30;} //right
    else if(key === 65 && player2.x >= 10) {player2.x -= 30;} //left
    else if(key === 83 && player2.y <= mycan.height-30) {player2.y += 30;} //down
    else if(key === 87 && player2.y >= 10) {player2.y -= 30;} //up  
  
  
  //player2(blue)
    if     (key === 39 && player.x <= mycan.width-25) {player.x += 30;} //right
    else if(key === 37 && player.x >= 10) {player.x -= 30;} //left
    else if(key === 40 && player.y <= mycan.height-25) {player.y += 30;} //down
    else if(key === 38 && player.y >= 10) {player.y -= 30;} //up
}

const draw = ()=>{
//player draw, and player colors
  ctx.clearRect(0,0, mycan.width, mycan.height);
  ctx.fillRect(player.x, player.y, player.w, player.h);
  ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
  ctx.fillRect(player2.x,player2.y, player2.w, player2.h);
  ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
  
  
  
};

setInterval(()=>{
  draw();
},1000/60);

//collision
//thsi is where i want to add collision
```

```css
html, body {
  margin:20;
  padding: 20;
}
canvas {
  display: block;
}

#mycan {
  background-size: 30px 30px;
  background-image:
    linear-gradient(to right, black 1px, transparent 1px),
    linear-gradient(to bottom, black 1px, green 1px);

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
<canvas id = mycan > </canvas>
    
    <font color = 'blue'> <h1>Player1 = blue</h1></font color>
    <font color = 'red'> <h1>Player2 = red</h1></font color>

  </head>
  <body>
    <main>
    </main>
    <script src="script.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've wrote you a function that checks the collision.

We do that by first checking  if the left edge of rect1 is further to the right than the right edge of rect2. We also check if the right edge of rect1 is further to the left than the left edge of rect2.

Same thing for bottom edge.

if all of those are false, the rectangles must be overlapping.

```js
const checkCollision = (rect1, rect2) => {
  return rect1.x < rect2.x + rect2.w &&rect1.x + rect1.w > rect2.x &&rect1.y < rect2.y + rect2.h &&rect1.y + rect1.h > rect2.y 
}
```

Comment: Remember that `if (boolean statement) return true else return false` is just `return boolean statement`. No reason to have an if statement here.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans RIght, my bad. Fixed it. I'm a little tired haha.

Comment: so if I want to have text that appears when they collide, would I do "if (return == true){}", or "if (return == false){}"?

Comment: if (checkCollision(player, player2)) {}

Comment: Although using proper naming conventions will help here too: if you're checking a state, use a state descriptor as a name, like `if (hasOverlap(player, player2)) { ... }` rather than `checkCollision`. The code _inside_ the function does the checking, but the result tells you whether there _is_ a collision.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans It says hasOverLap is not defined, so would i use a "let" statement to "define" it?

Comment: What he was saying is that me calling the `checkCollision` function checkCollision is not wanted, he would prefer to call it `hasOverlap` because the code _inside_ the function does the checking.-